# format a wbs column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to split then format a wbs column to have a prefix of zeroes using SQL?

Example: 1.2.15 to 1.002.015

Sample WBS Column content:

```
 - 1.1
 - 1.1.1
 - 1.1.2
 - 1.1.3
 - 1.2
```

Comment: Is this for MS-SQL Server? What version? If it's at least 2016, you can try playing with the STRING_SPLIT function.

Comment: I am using MS-SQL 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most beautiful code on Earth, but it does the trick:

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(100) = '1.2.15'
DECLARE @FORMAT VARCHAR(10) = '000'

DECLARE @P1 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @P2 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @P3 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @P4 VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE @PARTS INT = 1 + LEN(@STR) - LEN(REPLACE(@STR, '.', ''))

SELECT @P1 = PARSENAME(@STR, @PARTS)
SELECT @P2 = PARSENAME(@STR, @PARTS - 1) 
SELECT @P3 = PARSENAME(@STR, @PARTS - 2) 
SELECT @P4 = PARSENAME(@STR, @PARTS - 3)

SELECT @P2 = FORMAT(CAST(@P2 AS INT), @FORMAT)
SELECT @P3 = FORMAT(CAST(@P3 AS INT), @FORMAT)
SELECT @P4 = FORMAT(CAST(@P4 AS INT), @FORMAT)

SELECT ISNULL(@P1, '') + ISNULL('.' + @P2, '') + ISNULL('.' + @P3, '') + ISNULL('.' + @P4, '')
-- Output is 1.002.015
```

The key is to use the `PARSENAME` function. It's intended for parsing a fully qualified SQL object name, but here we will use it for WBS. I first find the number of points to know how many parts it has, as that function's second parameter is the part counting from the end. That way I can get the main version in `@P1`, the next one in `@P2`, etc.

Then I do a trick to add leading zeroes, and finally I just concatenate the numbers, avoiding nulling the string if one of them is NULL.

**Limitations:**

1. Only up to 4 parts (can't use this for 1.2.15.6.3)
2. Must be valid, no spaces and no . at the end

Comment: I edited your answer to automate the splitting then changed RIGHT to FORMAT. The code looks weird but it works.Thanks for the example to get me started.

Comment: I improved the answer by using `FORMAT`, which solved 2 of the limitations. What do you mean by "automate the splitting"?

Comment: I changed P1, P2... to a temp table where all the rows are the splitted wbs. This is how I got around limitation 1.

Comment: Oh, you mean the other answer? That one has nothing of my first response. :D Anyway the limitation comes from `PARSENAME`, so my code just matched that. As your examples only had 3 parts, my answer seemed enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @wbs nvarchar(MAX)
Set @wbs ='1.1.12.123.1234.12345.123456.1234567.123456789.1234567890'

DECLARE @XML AS XML
DECLARE @delimiter AS CHAR(1) = '.' -- wbs character seperator
SET @XML = CAST(('<WBS>'+REPLACE(@wbs, @delimiter,'</WBS><WBS>')+'</WBS>') AS XML)

DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) primary key, WBS INT)
INSERT INTO @tempTable SELECT N.value('.', 'INT') AS ID FROM @XML.nodes('WBS') AS T(N)

DECLARE @formattedWbs  varchar(MAX) = '',
        @wbsSplit  INT,
        @id INT,
        @skip bit = 1;

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  @tempTable)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @wbsSplit = WBS, @id = ID FROM @tempTable;

    IF @skip = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @formattedWbs +=  @wbsSplit;
            SET @skip = 0;
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @formattedWbs += '.' + FORMAT(@wbsSplit,'000#');
        END

    DELETE @tempTable Where ID = @id;
END

PRINT @formattedWbs;
```

Comment: Interesting, although maybe too convoluted and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE FUNCTION GetFormattedWBS (@wbs VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
BEGIN
    SET @wbs += '.'

```
DECLARE @formattedwbs NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @formattedwbs = '';

WHILE (CHARINDEX('.', @wbs) > 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @wbsnode INT;
    SET @wbsnode = SUBSTRING(@wbs, 1, CHARINDEX('.', @wbs) - 1);
    SET @formattedwbs +=  FORMAT(@wbsnode,'00000#') + '.';
    SET @wbs = SUBSTRING(@wbs, CHARINDEX('.', @wbs) + 1, len(@wbs));
END

SET @formattedwbs = SUBSTRING(@formattedWbs, 1, (len(@formattedWbs) - 1));  

RETURN @formattedwbs
```

END

Comment: ended up using this one.